# Is there any difference charged particle bends in magnetic field vs orbiting massive object?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, magnetic-fields, orbital-motion, velocity

Imagine 2 identical ions, one of them gets shepherd by a magnetic field while the other orbiting a massive object. Assume no outside forces involved and their velocity are equal, is there any difference between the 2?

Comment: Well charged particles can be repelled or attracted while gravitational force can only be attractive in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming here that the question concerns a constant magnetic field and the gravitational field of a point mass.

The force on the charge in the magnetic field is given by the Lorentz force:

$$\vec{F}_\mathrm{mag} = q \vec{v} \times \vec{B},$$

The mass in the gravitational field experiences a force

$$\vec{F}_\mathrm{grav} = \frac{G M m}{r^2} \hat{r}.$$

It’s clear that there are several differences in the particles’ motion:

- The equations of motion under the magnetic force give helical trajectories, whereas the gravitational force gives elliptical or hyperbolic trajectories depending on the initial conditions. The motion is only similar in the very special case of circular orbits.
- The particle in the gravitonal field’s acceleration is independent of its mass, while the particle in the magnetic field has an acceleration proportional to its charge/mass ratio.
- Unless the field strengths, mass, charge and initial conditions are tuned very carefully, even if the particles are in circular motion, it will not be at the same speed or radius.